# Adding Multi-User Approval Process in trac Workflow

Tags: workflow, trac

I have selected trac for my organization's project management tool; and I'd like to modify the default workflow as follows:

- A new "enhancement" ticket can be created by all members
- All new "enhancement" tickets need to be approved by the same 4 people before it can be assigned to a developer for work. "defect" & "task" tickets need not have the approval process.

I know I have to modify the [ticket-workflow] area of the trac.ini; but I can't figure out how to limit developer assignment until the ticket has essentially been approved.

I understand this is not an optimal workflow/process; but it's something that I have inherited and have to conform to until I can change it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the [TypedTicketWorkflowPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TypedTicketWorkflowPlugin) to restrict some transitions to specific ticket types only. Then update your `[ticket-workflow]` section along the lines of (untested):

```
[ticket-workflow]
assign = new,reopened -> assigned
assign.operations = set_owner
assign.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
assign.tickettype = defect, task

approve = new,reopened -> approved
approve.permissions = TICKET_ADMIN
approve.tickettype = enhancement

assign_enhancement = approved -> assigned
assign_enhancement.name = assign
assign_enhancement.operations = set_owner
assign_enhancement.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
```

You may have to tweak your `approve.permissions` options to allow only the right people to approve enhancement requests. I'm not sure if you can set usernames directly in the option, though.

Comment: I may have misunderstood: I thought you had to have enhancement requests approved by *one* of the four people, not all four.

Comment: Yup; it's all 4. I'm working on getting your solution put in place. Makes perfect sense though.  I'll have to see if Oliver's solution below will meet the requirements.  might have better luck changing the process though! LOL

Comment: @Typhon: May I ask what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Remy wrote, in order to get the multi-user approval bit of your request you could try to create distinct approved statii, e.g.

new, reopened -> approved1 -> approved2 -> approved3 -> approved4 -> assigned

(the above is not actual `[ticket-workflow]`-syntax obviously)